# Haskell squaring list elements and then adding them together

Tags: list, haskell, sum

I have written divisible_by2 to square all elements in a list that are even and are less than twenty. My second function sum2 sums all the of the elements of divisible_by2. I need help combining these function so that when running divisible_by2 both functions are compiled.

```
  divisible_by2 = [ x * x| x <- [2,4..18]]  
  sum2 = foldr (+) 1 divisible_by2
```

When running separately both functions give the correct output

```
   *Main> :r
   Ok, 1 module loaded.
   *Main> divisible_by2
   [4,16,36,64,100,144,196,256,324]
   *Main> sum2
   1141
   *Main>
```

Comment: Can't you just write `foldr (+) 1 [ x * x | x <- [2,4..18]]`? What specifically is the problem?

Comment: @Carcigenicate i need the list and the sum to print

Comment: You want both to print when you run divisible_by2? Printing should be limited.

Comment: I suggest creating a `main` function which prints the results of both of your existing functions.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you just want:

```
foo = (divisible_by2, sum2)
```

Also, that `1` in your `foldr (+) 1` looks weird. You probably want a `0` there instead, or perhaps want to just replace the whole `foldr` expression with a call to `sum`.